# ajax call in MVC results in "xmlhttprequest on the main thread is deprecated" warning

Tags: javascript, ajax, asp.net-mvc

Can anyone see why this ajax call would result in the console warning?  The warning suggests that it's a synchronous call but I can't see why that wold be.  It also returns the correct model data and loads it in the view, but the view appears 'broken', as if it hasn't loaded correctly.

> xmlhttprequest on the main thread is deprecated because of its
>   detrimental effects to the end user's experience

function:

```
function addSelectedModules () {
    event.preventDefault();
    $('#createLearningPathForm').validate();
    if ($('#createLearningPathForm').valid()) {

        return new Promise((resolve, reject) => {
            $.ajax({
                type: "POST",
                url: "/umbraco/Surface/CreateLearningPath/SetSelectedList",
                data: $('#createLearningPathForm').serialize(),
                success: function (data) {
                    resolve(data)
                },
                error: function (error) {
                    reject(error)
                }
            })
        })

    }
} 


$("#addSelectedModules").on("click", function () {
    addSelectedModules().then(data => {
        $("#lpPartial").html(data);
    })
        .catch(error => {
            console.log(error);
        })
});
```

Comment: try providing it with relevant contentType and dataType properties maybe? Also the default is `async:true` so you don't need the async property

Comment: tried that - also suspected it may be requiring a promise returned but still no joy

Answer (score 0):

If anyone else needs this I sorted it by updating the individual elements rather than what I was doing which was updating the top level div:

```
$("#addSelectedModules").on("click", function () {
    addSelectedModules().then(data => {
        var selected = $(data).find('#selectedDiv').html();
        var select = $(data).find('#selectItems').html();

        $("#selectedDiv").html(selected);
        $("#selectItems").html(select);
    })
        .catch(error => {
            console.log(error);
        })
});
```